# How to place a the label/description of a django char field above the textbox

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a django form displayed like this in a template:

```html
<div>
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Which contains a field like this:

```
class CreateArticle(forms.Form):
    organization = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Organization.objects.all())
    introduction_text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

As you can see in the screenshot below the field description (Introduction text) ends up to the left of the textfield, I would like it to be placed above.

[image: Screenshot link]

Is there a way to do this in the field definition in the form, without changing the projects css files and/or making the template file more complicated?

Comment: The low-level form rendering API is documented here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/renderers/ - did you read it ?

Comment: Short answer: there are ways to change the rendering without touching _this_ template nor the css, but this will takes at least as much work. The simplest solution is still to apply proper styling (css).

Comment: ok, I guess it might be better to do it using css then, thank you for the link to the widgets page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I have found an easy way to do this without touching the css files (which I shouldn't do in this particular project). Just add a 100% width attribute to the text field and it will fill up whatever

/ or whatever it is part of which will automatically place the text on top of the text field.

```
introduction_text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'style': "width:100%;"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding `help` in .py field you can make label/description above the text box.

Like this -> `introduction_text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,help='You can add description here')`

Comment: to me it seems like the help text just ends up after the input field (to the right), so this does not help ... also I think it needs to be help_text='You can add description here'

Answer (score -1):

Wrapping the text with a `div` will let textarea to come on a new line. Since `div` is a block element.

```html
<div>
  <form method="post">
      <div>
        {% csrf_token %}
      </div>
      <div>
        {{ form.as_p }}
      </div>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `<p>` is a block element too... and wrapping all the paragraphs in a div will not solve the OP's question.

Comment: don't wrap the csrf_token in a div